# System of non linear differential equation numerical solution

Tags: numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of non-linear differential equations. My system has 15 parameters which I have to estimate, I am using optimization for it. Some of parameters can make my system be stiff and some maybe not. This can make my optimization result become garbage because the ODE solver terminates with an error. What is the best way to deal with such problem?

If I solve it with an implicit method, maybe my system will be not stiff, will it be ok? If yes what is the best numerical method you suggest.

Thanks a-lot.

Comment: This question seems off-topic, as no direct code problem is related. Questions about selections of numerical algorithms and methods might be better suited for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming but about numerical analysis

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question seems off-topic, as no direct code problem is related. Questions about selections of numerical algorithms and methods might be better suited for scicomp.stackexchange.com.